# Python script as service in init.d, is it worth to daemonize?

Tags: python, init.d, python-daemon, start-stop-daemon

I have few python scripts that I want to have as a service in a system. My initial approach was to use python-daemon and it worked. Process was detached and running in the background. Then I have learnt that init.d provides wrapper to what I need, that is daemon-start-stop.

Right now I do no know what to do. Is it worthy to get red of python-daemon or opposite, or keep them both (in such case python-daemon has to be launched with detach=False).

If someone has experience with init.d scripts and daemons, I would love to hear you out.

Few questions, that I am looking answers for:
 - pros & cons between those two solutions
 - which one is simpler and yet more robust solution
 - what problems did you find in the past

I know this question might be a bit like introduction to discussion because there might be no clear answer as such. However I want to learn other people mistakes before I spring the trap on myself.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion. You may want to daemonize, use a watchdog like `supervisord` or some blessed OS mechanism like `init.d`. there is no right answer. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I will update some helper questions, what I wanted to hear is some pros & cons or what is simpler to maintain.